# exchange 2010 activesync policies.. Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, activesync

Im trying to setup an activesync policy in exchange 2010, and apply that policy to my OU "LVM". This is the problem I am running into,

I have two top OUs

1. Computers
2. Users

Each one of these has a sub OU name LVM

so whenever I run the get-mailbox -organizationalunit "LVM" it returns:

```
[PS] C:\Users\administrator.JEWELS\Desktop>Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "LVM"
Multiple organizational units match identity "LVM". Specify a unique value.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ManagementObjectAmbiguousException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DDC484A6
```

How can i get around the multiple organization units match identity "LVM"?

Do I have to rename one of the OUs, or is there another was i can use this command? Will renaming the OU may cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried this in a virtual machine, and it will get you what you want (obviously replace with your own domain name and OU structure).

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "corp.acme-widgets.com/Acme Widgets/Users/LVM"

Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
LVM 1                     lvm1                 svr01            unlimited
LVM 3                     lvm3                 svr01            unlimited
```

FWIW, I created `lvm2` in `Acme Widgets/Computers/LVM` just to check it was pulling info from the correct OU.